# media query for iOS 11 Safari not triggered when address bar is shown

Tags: ios, css, safari

Im trying to detect when iOS safari is displaying the address bar. I have two media queries:

this is targeting when the address bar is showing.

```
@media only screen and (width: 736px) and (height: 364px)
```

this is for when its not

```
@media only screen and (width: 736px) and (height: 414px)
```

even when the window.innerHeight is 364px, the media query for 414px overrides the one for 364px.

Is there a way to detect when its being displayed?  Or are my media queries wrong?

Comment: Why aren't you using `min-width` or `max-width` instead of `width`?

Comment: because other than this specific case, im trying to stay away from device specific media queries.

Comment: I've never seen `width` used anywhere; it might not be valid. Try`(device-width:414px)` or `(min-width:414px) and (max-width:414px)` instead.

Comment: device-width is deprecated, but the issue isnt that the width isnt being hit, its that it hits 414 even if the height is 364.

Comment: Try using both `min-width` and `max-width` then. Assuming you have the dimensions correct, I can only assume that the browser is interpreting `width` as `max-width`.

Comment: Hey. Have you solved this? Seems to be I have the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67622522/media-max-height-is-not-equal-to-window-innerheight